# AVR Programming (C- Language)

Tags: c, embedded, avr, atmel

What is the meaning of

```
TIFR0 = 1<<TOV0;
```

Is it means we are writing 1 to TOV0 bit of TIFR0?

Comment: Read about the shift left operator.

Comment: And `0` to all the other bits. It shifts `1` left to the bit position specified by `TOV0`. But it would be more general as `1u << TOV0`.

Comment: You can't do embedded systems programming without studying the utter basics of C first. That includes all bitwise operations, binary notation, hex notation. Start with reading a beginner-level book then take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

No. That means we are writing 1 to a bit at position `TOV0`, **while writing 0 to all other bits** in `TIFR0` register.

`<<` is a bitwise shift left operation, which results equals to all bits of the source number, shifted left in their binary representation.

`1` is a number where only the first bit (i.e. the bit at position `#0`) is set. Therefore `1 << n` moves that bit `n` positions left, and gives you a number where only bit `#n` is set, but all other bits are cleared.

`TOV0` is a macro, which defines the position of bit `TOV0`.

Be careful when using simple assignment like that, because it will clear all other bits.

If you want to modify the only bit, you may use a *bitwise or*:

`TIFR0 |= 1<<TOV0;`